# Problems with VS Code JavaScript Intellisense and ES6 Import with Minified & Non-minified Version of JS

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, es6-modules, terser

Below is my Firebase hosting project folder structure:

```
projectFolder/store/public/scripts/*.min.js
projectFolder/src/*.js
```

After running `terser`, all my `projectFolder/src/*.js` will be minified to `projectFolder/store/public/scripts/*.min.js` as shown below:

**EDIT: As requested by @Bergi, this is how my `terser` script looks like:**

```
call terser src/site-ui-components.js -o store/public/scripts/site-ui-components.min.js -c -m
echo site-ui-components.min.js: Done.
call terser src/login.js -o store/public/scripts/login.min.js -c -m
echo login.min.js: Done.
call terser src/register.js -o store/public/scripts/register.min.js -c -m
echo register.min.js: Done.
call terser src/profile.js -o store/public/scripts/profile.min.js -c -m
echo profile.min.js: Done.
```

In my ES6 import, I do the following:

```
import { something1, something2 } from "/scripts/something.min.js";
```

This works fine during runtime, but I **lose all the vs code intellisense** for `something1` and `something2` during development time. If I enable the intellisense by doing the following, during runtime, my code breaks because obviously, it couldn't find `"./something.js"`:

```
import { something1, something2 } from "./something.js"; // Error, something.min.js not found
```

I do not want to do something silly by adding the `*.min.js` to my all my **non-minified js** just to make both of them work. Secondly, I try to avoid using [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) by writing extra code to adapt to different environment.

**So my question is:**

1. How can I keep my intellisense for ES6 import without breaking my code during runtime?
2. Is there something wrong with my folder structure? E.g. not compliant to the best/common practice? Any recommendation?
3. Shall I, might as well, make the minified and non-minified js files as simply `*.js` instead?

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If terser is renaming the files it should also update the imports respectively. Can you show us how you are using it? Please post your full build script.

Comment: @Bergi : Done, thanks for looking at the problem.

Comment: I think the proper way to go is to change your build script so that it rewrites the module imports to add `.min` when copying them to the output directory, so that the source module imports resolve to source modules and the output module imports resolve to output modules. This would probably happen automatically if you used terser as part of a bundler like webpack or rollup, but I don't know how to do it manually (sans `sed`/`awk`) - `terser` itself doesn't seem to have options for this

Comment: Yeah, when you told me about `terser`, I did some further research on the command line parameters too, but still can't find any solution out of it. The **auto change import path** is for renaming or moving files but `terser` is **generating** the output files instead. Perhaps as what you mentioned, I should use it together with webpack but I'm not using it at the moment. Too much of learning curve and changes required.

Answer (score 1):

After so much of searching and reading, I finally managed to figure out the use of `baseUrl` and `paths` of `jsconfig.json` in VS Code to solve my problems:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
     "paths": {
         "/scripts/*": ["./store/public/scripts/*"]
     }
  }
}
```

**Explanations:**

The goal here is to make the following import works for both `/src/*.js` and `/store/public/scripts/*.min.js` without losing the inteliisense:

```
import { something1, something2 } from "/scripts/something.min.js";
```

For my case, it doesn't really matter if my JS in `src` references to `/scripts/*.min.js` because `*.min.js` are always getting from the latest object interfaces from the `src`. Whenever I change any JS file in the `src`, I just run my `terser` script for the new changes to be reflected by the intellisense, so not a big deal. Therefore, in order for both `/src/*.js` and `/scripts/*.min.js` to import from the same source without breaking the code during runtime, I can configure my `jsconfig.json` as shown above to achieve this goal:

```
"baseUrl": "."
```

The `"."` is the `projectFolder` where my `jsconfig.json` is stored, namely `projectFolder/jsconfig.json`.

```
"paths": {
   "/scripts/*": ["./store/public/scripts/*"]
}
```

`"/scripts/*"` is the string pattern or import path that I use to reference the exported module files. So when I `import { something1 } from "/scripts/something.min.js"`, VS Code always refers to `"./store/public/scripts/*"` for the intellisense.

I hope my explanation is clear to everyone.